# Multiple array modifiers and object offset rotation

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I have this hexagonal column that I made with an array modifier (with a rotated empty offset), since all 6 sides of it are the same. I need that column (the result of the first array) to be duplicated in a circle as well. When using empties as the offset, you need to position the object's origin where the empty is. The problem I face now is that I cannot use a second array modifier with an object offset on top of the first one, because I would have to move the object's origin (which is already positioned to make the first array work, and moving it will change the first array's result). Obviously I cannot have 2 origins for the same object. I know I can APPLY the first array and then move my origin for the second array but the whole point is to try to avoid this in case I need to modify the column itself. Any way I can make this work?

[image]

Comment: Try to put the second empty  of second array modifier at the location of the column and then rotate it relative to the center of the circle where the arrays should be(360/number of columns).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add a second array modifier to your column.
2. Crate a second empty at the same location of origin of the column and assign it in the second array modifier.
3. Set the 3D Cursor where the center of the array should be.
4. Set Pivot Point to 3D Cursor
5. Select the second empty and rotate it on Z axis (360/count number in second array modifier)

[image]